# OpenLayers vector feature not being highlighted

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm trying to highlight a clicked area of a layer using a vector:

```
var highlightLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Highlighted Features", {
    displayInLayerSwitcher: false,
    styleMap: mystyle
});
// the layer is added to the map, GetFeatureInfo controls setup and added etc.
```

...and this is the callback for the GetFeatureInfo call:

```
function showInfo(event) {
    console.log( event );
    highlightLayer.addFeatures( event.features[0] );
    highlightLayer.redraw(); // i've tried without this too
    console.log( highlightLayer );
}
```

No highlighting happens though. The object (event) passed to the callback looks alright, it has a features property containing an array with one vector feature element. But while inspecting the `highlightLayer` vector object printed to the console in the callback, I noticed that the returned vector feature object has been added to the `unrenderedfeatures` property.

OpenLayers obviously could not render the feature, but I don't understand the reason. There doesn't seem to be a callback for detecting problems with rendering. How could I debug this further?

**Edit:**
Also, I noticed that the `bounds` property of the returned vector feature is `undefined`. Does OpenLayers need this to be a valid `OpenLayers.Bounds` object? The `geometry.bounds` object, however, is defined and is a valid `OpenLayers.Bounds` object.

**Edit2**:
I dug into the OpenLayers source and added some debug logging. It turns out that the redrawFeature function belonging to the renderer is returning false, resulting in the feature to be added to the unrenderedfeatures property of the vector layer. The reason it's returning false is because of this:

```
var bounds = feature.geometry.getBounds();
var worldBounds;
if (this.map.baseLayer && this.map.baseLayer.wrapDateLine) {
    worldBounds = this.map.getMaxExtent();
}
var intersects = bounds && bounds.intersectsBounds(this.extent, {worldBounds: worldBounds});
rendered = (style.display !== "none") && !!bounds && intersects;
```

The `intersects` variable is **false**. Why might that be? Could it be that some sort of conversion is needed on the bounds values returned from the GetFeatureInfo call?

Here's some logging of the points that are compared in the `intersectsBounds` function:

Feature / Renderer-Canvas-Extent
Bottom: 719322.39 / 7022915.0167624
Left: 689914.61 / -740991.87193189
Right: 689947.66 / -740514.14050517
Top: 719349.21 / 7023273.3153324

Comment: Try this in http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is impossible to know without a minimal working example of your problem -- there are too many unknown variables, such as your CRS, to even hazard a guess.